# Looking for memory efficient design

Tags: java, optimization

I'm running some experiments over a large dataset and would like to optimize a particular part.  Currently, I have 5-6 `Model`s each of which stores a mapping from `Topic`s to `List` of `String`s. The set of `Topic`s is large and the same between each `Model`, so there must be a better way.  Ultimately the query I need to perform is: what is the `String` in position x of the `List` for some `Model`-`Topic` combination.

One of the problems with using the mapping method is that if there are say 500k-5M topics, each has a list of 20 strings. Then my `Map<Model, Map<Topic, List<String>>>` is going to be massive.

Comment: List and ArrayList's `get` functions are [O(1)](http://www.coderfriendly.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/java_collections_v2.pdf)....

Comment: How many times are entries going to be inserted in to the data structure? How many times are you going to be running retrievals? If you are going to be doing many retrievals and few insertions/deletions a sorted data structure would be great.

Comment: When say large, how many million are you talking about?

Comment: What does your data look like? Perhaps you can create your objects differently and just store references to that data without duplicating it.

Comment: Is the list of strings fixed?  This sounds like a Guava `Table` -- maybe even an `ArrayTable`, if the models and topics are fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried SortedSet / Maps?  Sounds like you need to optimize your search, sorted collections (like TreeMap) should be log(n) while regular list is O(1).  Of course, this kind of thing is something at which databases excel...

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Topic` and `Model` to construct a composite key in a single Map, e.g.

```
map.put(topic1_id + model1_id, list1_1);
map.put(topic1_id + model2_id, list1_2);
...
map.get(topic_id + model_id)
```

where the IDs are Strings (or a similar scheme could be used with numeric identifiers).

A similar approach is to assign each topic and model a unique number, then store the lists of strings in arrays, so looking up the list for a given combination is a matter of looking up two indexes, then accessing a given location in a 2D array. (however, this is easier when you know the number of topics and models in advance of constructing the data structure)

For memory efficiency, also consider the small details. In general, you want to minimise the number of Objects - each Object carries an overhead. ArrayLists can have a lot of wasted space as they grow dynamically, doubling in size when they exceed their current capacity. If you can pre-size them to the required capacity (or use an array instead) then you can save a lot of memory. The same applies when using large numbers of small HashMaps.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear where/how you want to achieve "memory efficiency".  First one needs to look at the particulars of your detailed data to see how much storage that consumes, then examine various ways of organizing it and analyze their efficiency in terms of % overhead vs your "real" data.

A brief glance shows that a HashMap, when you consider the associated tables, has about 80 bytes of overhead per entry.  An ArrayList looks to average out around 10-12.  Without looking, I would guess that a TreeMap would be more than a HashMap -- maybe 100.

Generally speaking, links within your own objects will be "cheaper", both in storage and speed to access, than links using these aggregating objects.  But the aggregating objects are convenient to use, and have been "optimized" to a degree.

(But looking at your update, you probably should be looking at a DB application, rather than holding everything in heap.)

Comment: What makes you say 100 bytes for TreeMap? I agree with everything else but in a TreeMap I would expect about 12-24 bytes overhead. Just 3 refs: parent, left child and right child with 32 or 64 bit pointers.

Comment: @JohnWatts -- Well, right off the bat you've got 24-32 bytes of object overhead.  Then you add the necessary fields on top of that.

Comment: @JohnWatts -- And in addition to the object header a TreeMap node has 5 pointer fields and a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

One possible data structure is a hierarchy of maps, leading to an array of Strings. E.g.:

```
HashMap<Model, HashMap<Topic, String[]>> map;
```

A query function would then look like:

```
public String query(Model model, Topic topic, int x) {

    HashMap<Topic, String[]> childMap = map.get(model);
    if (childMap == null) {
       return null;
    }

    String[] list = childMap.get(topic);
    if (list == null) { 
        return null;
    }

    return list[x];
}
```

Presuming your Model and Topic structures implement `hashCode()` and `equals()` reasonably, the query performance should be quite good.

One potential weakness: I'm assuming you need to index a large number of Model/Topic combinations, and related lists of Strings (if not, you presumably wouldn't be asking about optimization). My guess is that the child String[] arrays will consume a large amount of memory. Each array is a Java object (about 20 bytes) + a pointer at each array location.

2 suggestions there:

1) If many Model/Topic combinations share the same set of Strings, you could gain quite a lot by sharing those `String[]` instances.

2) If you're using a 64-bit VM, be sure to use compressed ordinary object pointers (`-XX:+UseCompressedOops`). That will at least keep most of the pointers to 4 bytes instead of 8. Compressed OOPs is the default since 1.6.0_23, so a relatively recent VM will save you some memory here.

Answer (score 0):

One other possibility not mentioned is store the strings using `String[][][]` and models and topics in a `List` such as `ArrayList` and then at query time:

```
public String query(Model model, Topic topic, int x) {
   return strings[models.indexOf(model)][topics.indexOf(topic)][x];
}
```

It could be further improved for speed if the topics and models were sorted, then binary search rather than `indexOf` could be used.